# Align all text-containing table columns left, and all number-containing columns right

Tags: html, css

First time posting on the forum.

I'm not a developer and only try to write code occassionally for personal purposes. Forgive my ignorance.

What I'm trying to do is this: I create an HTML table and I want some way (ideally using only CSS) to have all columns containing text aligned left, and all columns containing numbers aligned right; basically what Excel or any spreadsheet program does.

I understand I could go about manually aligning individual td's, but I'm rather looking for some way to make it happen automatically and universally across multiple large tables.

I hope my explanation is intelligible enough. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can only do that in css, but I have an option for you with javascript.

I just made this simple code that check in your table if your td is a number or text. The script only add a class for each td.

```css
table,
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.align-right {
    text-align: right;
}

td.align-left {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Something</th>
                <th>Something else</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>23454</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    const tdEls = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("td"));

    tdEls.forEach((td) => {
        if (isNaN(td.innerHTML)) {
            td.classList.add("align-left");
        } else {
            td.classList.add("align-right");
        }
    });
</script>
```